# Visual Studio 2022, hot reload button is grayed out

Tags: visual-studio-2022, maui

I am new to MAUI, while I was starting up a project to mess around with the starter app, I noticed I can no longer hot reload, the button is grayed out and disabled. These are the changes I have tried.

- Resetting options to default
- Change from .NET 7 to 6
- Reinstalled Visual Studio
- Disabled "Enable Hot Reload and Edit and Continue when debugging."
- Enabled all XAML Hot Reload options
- Running without and with debugging
- Making a new android device to test on

While it does not work now, when I first installed MAUI, I was able to hot reload when I first made a starting android emulator, I don't believe I used it, but I know it was not grayed out and was red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling hot reload on save allowed me to edit my work.

Debug -> options -> Apply Hot Reload on File Save.

The final answer was a reset to my machine, after resetting windows from scratch and reinstalling VS 2022 again, the hot reload button worked perfectly fine.